# Java Spring:Heroku app stopped working after i added Google analytics js code

Tags: java, spring, heroku, google-analytics, thymeleaf

I searched on Stack Overflow about this issue and couldn't find something related to spring.
My app was working fine without any issues until I added the Google Analytics js code on each of my html pages.
The app uses java spring, thymeleaf, cleardDB(mysql).
The logs say the following:

```
2020-07-29T07:43:52.270276+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-29 07:43:52.270  INFO 4 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-07-29T07:43:52.900839+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-29 07:43:52.900  INFO 4 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-07-29T07:43:52.919019+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-29 07:43:52.918  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.example.MyApp.MyAppApplication   : Started MyAppApplication in 10.278 seconds (JVM running for 11.223)
2020-07-29T07:45:14.507148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=myApp.herokuapp.com request_id=39b52e32-a1e7-42f2-9214-3aead7ca50a4 fwd="86.124.21.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T07:46:16.669611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=myApp.herokuapp.com request_id=5c227043-6b16-411e-9ca4-247ffd1327ec fwd="86.124.21.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T07:46:18.036552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
2020-07-29T07:47:02.080138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-29T07:47:02.167156+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-29 07:47:02.166  INFO 4 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-29T07:47:02.169612+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-07-29 07:47:02.169  INFO 4 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

I looked on heroku error status codes , and the only thing it suggest for this error is to increase my boot timeout window which I did to 120 seconds. Still the issue persisted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:After removing the Google Analytics scripts from the html pages.

```
2020-07-29T08:18:58.663096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=myApp.herokuapp.com request_id=afc39c8e-c8d0-4b92-9564-802951e628c1 fwd="86.124.21.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T08:19:41.283231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2020-07-29T08:19:41.301701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-07-29T08:19:41.392546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-07-29T08:19:41.423502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h20-app-boot-timeout

> The router will enqueue requests for 75 seconds **while waiting for starting processes to reach an “up” state**. If after 75 seconds, no web dynos have reached an “up” state, the router logs H20 and serves a standard error page.

You probably are also getting R10 error which would put your starting process in the up state.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout

> A web process took longer than 60 seconds to bind to its assigned `$PORT`.

The error is that you are not listening to the `$PORT` within 60 seconds after starting your program.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, no there is no r10 error code.I have updated my initial post with the full error codes, please take a look.

Comment: It is still missing a lot of logs provided by `heroku[web.1]`. Provide the logs beginning from `State changed from created to starting`

Comment: ok, added most of the logs that appear on the heroku platform log tab.Do you need more information? Regarding the analytics. I added both scripts right under the <head> tag on all pages as they say, if that matters.

Comment: You have not provided the log where the state changed from created to starting. `State changed from starting to down`. This indicates 2 things. It didn't throw any errors (else the state would have changed to `crashed`) and it failed to bind to the `$PORT` (else the state would have changed to `up`).

Comment: ok i have removed the scripts from the page, and instead of working like before, it now throws an R10 error, i have modified my initial message with the new logs

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Java/Spring. So I might not be able to help you further. Include `pom.*`,  `Procfile` and the source code of where you are listening on the `$PORT`. Your project fails to listen to the `$PORT`.

Comment: I did not get this error before adding google analytics to the templates.so now after deleting the scripts i don't know why i get it.The app was working fine before.here is the procfile                                                                         
 ```web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS```

Comment: The issue can really be anything. Try to compare the different revisions. Something is different. One issue I can imagine to be the problem is for instance: You modified the template. The template goes through the build generator. The build generator fails and there are no html, js, css files. Your code is trying to serve nothing and fails there. Or do you create the static build files manually and commit that?

Comment: I looked through the previous versions the only thing i have added is the 2 scripts provided by google analytics, nothing else.If i do a rollback from version 6 wich has the google analytics stuff to version 5 wich doesn't have the scripts, it works flawlessly.But after i removed every analitcs script in version 7 so that it looks like the working v5 and redeployed ,it still doesn't work anymore.How can this break my whole app?What do you mean build generator fails?where can i look to see if my code does serve something or not?What do you mean by me creating the static files manually?